# Python/Pygame What is inherited from pygame.sprite.Sprite?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

When creating a derived class, what is actually being inherited from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`? It's something that doesn't need to be set up anywhere else in a class, so what is it? Are there actual methods included with it or does python/pygame just know what do with it?

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite

Answer (score 1):

[Use the source, Luke!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2we_B6hDrY) @ [pygame.sprite.Sprite](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/dc57da440ac3415ff679c0e9a1d6d75d949b2db9/lib/sprite.py?at=default#cl-106) inherits `object`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Look it up on the original pygame website:
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite

Comment: converting a comment to the question into an answer is ... suboptimal (to put it mildly), particularly if it's link-only